# Google Text-to-Speech : Error could not auto authenticate

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I'm using the google text to speech API in the powershell.  I've created the project, enabled the api, created the key, when I tell it this
$cred = gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
$headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $cred" }

Invoke-WebRequest `-Method POST`
-Headers $headers `-ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`
-InFile request.json `
-Uri "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize" | Select-Object -Expand Content

And this is after I set the environment, I get this error message
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.application-default.print-access-token) Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
At line:4 char:1

- Invoke-WebRequest `
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
  eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
  ```

I have attempted to recreate the key thinking that was maybe the issue but I keep getting this error here no matter what I do, I am using this code to point to the key
$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\IVR2\IVR2-ba991f7cce6a.json

Answer (score 0):

For an application, you would set the env variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS which is the location of your service account json file.

It looks like you're using gcloud to get creds and including an authorization header. That should work too. Does your gcloud command return an error?